# Hover effect in Html

Tags: html, css

I want to add a hover effect to images of my web site.
My pics are in

and cant add this effects.
The code:

```
    <ul class="grid">

        <li class="small" style="background-image: url(https://s30.postimg.org/b5q9obsxd/IMG_6050_copy.jpg);"></li>
        <li class="large" style="background-image: url(https://s24.postimg.org/mpyapvjz9/IMG_4995_copy.jpg);"></li>
```

Comment: your question is not clear , please edit your question

Comment: What hover effect do you want to see?

Comment: What do you want the hover effect to do? .grid li:hover { Your hover effect goes here. }

Comment: Read about the :hover pseudo-class on the internet!

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp this link will help you

Answer (score 0):

Use `li:hover` to apply your CSS on hover.

```css
li:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>LI</li>
  <li>LI</li>
  <li>LI</li>
  <li>LI</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use hover as below:

```
li:hover{
 background-color: #C8E7F1;
}
```

Comment: the dot is in (.li) is used if you are selecting a class. You are just selecting a html element, just li should do the work

Answer (score 0):

Check the hover effect example.

```css
.grid {
  list-style: none;
}
.grid li {
  opacity: 1;
  float: left;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.grid li:hover {
  opacity: 0.80;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid">

  <li class="small" style="background-image: url(https://s30.postimg.org/b5q9obsxd/IMG_6050_copy.jpg);"></li>
  <li class="large" style="background-image: url(https://s24.postimg.org/mpyapvjz9/IMG_4995_copy.jpg);"></li>
</ul>
```